# Dividing two parameters from string in R

Tags: r, string

I want to make a function in r which will divide two parameters from an undefined long string.

The input parameter will be smothing like this:

```
a <- "1-2931.0356917386653/2-5329.690008269986/4-857.0836085854653"
b <- "1-56455.0/2-70413.0/4-4247.0"
```

the numbers with hyphen ("1-","2-","4-") and divide sign ("/")help us to find unique data and the correlation with two parameters, and it is not counted while I will divide the numbers.

Output has to be:

```
C <- a/b
```

where I will divide `2931.0356917386653 / 56455.0 , 5329.690008269986 / 70413.0, 857.0836085854653 / 4247.0` which give this results:

```
C =  1-0.051918/2-0.0756918/4-0.2018091
```

The length of the string is not fixed, and the numbers (1- , 2- , 3-, etc.) could more or less, depend on the data.

I want to use this function to divide two csv table, with the cell by cell.

Comment: An unrelated tip: try to avoid mixing capital letters with lowercase letters as variable names (C vs. a). It gets confusing when you write longer programs.

Answer (score 0):

```
divide<-function(a,b){
                        a<-strsplit(x = a,split = "\\/")
                        b<-strsplit(x = b,split = "\\/")
                        a<-sapply(a,function(t){
 gsub(pattern = "^[0-9]-",fixed = F,replacement = "",x = t)},simplify = T)
                        b<-sapply(b,function(t){
 gsub(pattern = "^[0-9]-",fixed = F,replacement = "",x = t)},simplify = T)
 a<-as.numeric(a)
 b<-as.numeric(b)
 return(a/b)
}

#> divide(a,b)
#> [1] 0.05191809 0.07569185 0.20180918
```

This is not the best approach to pass two similar type of parameters to the same function together for same type of pre-processing. Better approach would be just to pass 1 string at a time and retrieve a numeric vector and then simply try `a/b`: something like this:

```
preprocess<-function(n){
                        n<-strsplit(x = n,split = "\\/")
                        n<-sapply(n,function(t){
 gsub(pattern = "^[0-9]-",fixed = F,replacement = "",x = t)},simplify = T)
 n<-as.numeric(n)
 return(n)
}

a<-preprocess(a)
b<-preprocess(b)
a/b

#> [1] 0.05191809 0.07569185 0.20180918
```

Comment: @GáborKőrösi If this solved your problem, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sapply(strsplit(a,split = "/"),function(x) as.numeric(gsub(".-","",x)))/sapply(strsplit(b,split = "/"),function(x) as.numeric(gsub(".-","",x)))
#[,1]
#[1,] 0.0519181
#[2,] 0.0756918
#[3,] 0.2018092
```